# Как определить запущен ли процесс?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

Нужно определить запущен ли процесс с конкретным именем в node js. Пробую запускать exec.

При вызове команды в командной строке ubuntu.

```
ps -A
```

Процессы выводятся, но имя процесса обрезается если длинное.
Есть ли в node js средства для проверки запущенных процессов?
Если нет то какой командой можно получить список запущенных процессов с полным названием процесса?

Comment: для node есть хороший пакет `pm2` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, только он тут совсем не при чём...

Comment: @Qwertiy связанное с командой `ps` - да. Но  `pm2` это менеджер процессов для node.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, если я правильно понимаю, он хочет из nodejs получать список чужих процессов и что-то в нём искать.

Comment: Ну да. Нужно удостовериться что аналогичный процесс не был запущен, чтобы не запускать следующий.

Comment: ну типовое же решение! правильно формулируйте вопрос, пожалуйста, а не описывайте суть где-то глубоко в комментариях! google://язык+pid+file, первая ссылка: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npid

Comment: может, лучше взглянуть в сторону https://www.npmjs.com/package/singleton-process

Comment: *pgrep -a имя_процесса*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно скажу, не работал с nodejs , но могу предположить, что тебе нужно использовать утилиту ps с аргументами aux.

ps aux, выведет список процессов с указанием комманд, которыми они запустились.

ну ещё в интернетах рекомендуют пакет ps-list (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-list)